# Android facebook integration error Requires extended permission: read_stream"

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm making an android app which can get all facebook posts as well as liked pages. the problem is when i logged in using developer account, it returns all information correctly but when i tried to login from some random account, it gives me error which is,

```
{  "error":
     {   
         "message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream",
         "type":"OAuthException","code":200
     }
}
```

i tried different solutions on google and also from stackoverflow but didn't get the work done.

i'm using following graph api url,

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?fields=type,message,source,from,comments.summary(true),likes.summary(true),attachments%7Bsubattachments,media%7D&permission=read_stream&access_token={access_token}

i gives these permissions at login permission,

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("read_stream", "user_likes",
            "user_posts");
```

Please help me with the right and perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

> This permission is not approved for apps that are on platforms where Facebook is not already available.

according to [Facebook Terms And Conditions ChangeLog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Comment: Your answer didn't solve my problem. I test my app on real device where facebook app is already installed but it gives me same error

Comment: as u r using developer account

Comment: Means i didnt understand

Comment: Developer account can get all permissions as for testing purpose, but when you make the app available for end users, FB wont allow them access before approval.

Comment: that's the point, how i can make it available or accessible for end user

Comment: Facebook Wont Approve This Permission For **ANDROID**

Comment: then how can we make apps using facebook integration, if fb didn't allow to do this

Comment: how can you say that, is this is written in somewhere documentation that their is this type of restriction

Comment: Please send your app for approval from facebook using [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0) try it once

Comment: `read_stream`

Provides access to read the posts in a person's News Feed, or the posts on their Profile.

Review
If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) how your app uses it.

Limited Use
This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

this is what FB Documentation States.